# Determine the value without solving for a

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this question at the bottom of [this](https://www.siyavula.com/read/maths/grade-10/01-algebraic-expressions-05#toc-id-15) page, the last question on the page. I've been taught how to handle this question but I couldn't figure this one out so I'd like to show how the website solved it and I please want someone to explain to me the steps they took to get to their answer. Assume that I know nothing about algebra.

Given that $a+\frac{1}{3a}=2$, determine the value of $a^3+\frac{1}{27a^3}$ without solving for $a$.

$$a^3+\frac{1}{27a^3} = (a+\frac{1}{3a})(a^2-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9a^2})=2(a^2-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9a^2})$$

$$a^2-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9a^2}=(a+\frac{1}{3a})^2-1=4-1=3$$

$$a^3+\frac{1}{27a^3}=2(3)=6$$

Apologies, I don't know how to put new lines in the middle of equations so if you want clarity you can check on the [site](https://www.siyavula.com/read/maths/grade-10/01-algebraic-expressions-05#toc-id-15), it's literally the last question on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line: It is easy to check that $\displaystyle\left(a+\frac1{3a}\right)\left(a^2-\frac13+\frac1{9a^2}\right)=a^3+\frac1{27a^3}$. Now, use the fact the you know that $\displaystyle a+\frac1{3a}=2$.

Second line: $\displaystyle\left(a+\frac1{3a}\right)^2=a^2+\frac23+\frac1{9a^2}$ and therefore $\displaystyle\left(a+\frac1{3a}\right)^2-1=a^2-\frac13+\frac1{9a^2}$. Now, use again the fact the you know that $\displaystyle a+\frac1a=2$.

Third line: From the second line, you know that $\displaystyle\left(a+\frac1{3a}\right)^2-1=a^2-\frac13+\frac1{9a^2}=3$ and from the first line you know that $\displaystyle a^3+\frac1{27a^3}$ is twice this number. Therefore, $\displaystyle a^3+\frac1{27a^3}=2\times 3=6$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

use

> $$(a+b)^3=a^3+3ab (a+b)+b^3$$

with $b=\frac {1}{3a} $, observe that
$3ab=1$,
and $$27=3^3$$

With $a+b=2$, the result is $$2^3-2=6$$